# Prevent RC commands from running

Tags: linux, boot

I am running a shell script from a rc file in Linux. The shell script is going into a loop which runs for 8 hours. Now I want to prevent the shell script from running when Linux boots or I need to find a way to kill the shell script when it is running. I tried using `killall`, `kill $!` and `Ctrl+C` etc. Nothing seems to work. Can you suggest a way out. I am new to Linux.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by new123456, you can just `chmod -x` the script to disable it (or fix it, or just delete it...).

To get into your system to do this, there are several options:

- Try booting into single-user mode: Usually you can pass the boot option "S" on the kernel command line (edit the kernel command line in your boot manager, e.g. GRUB), then you'll boot into single-user mode. Some distros (e.g. Ubuntu) also offer a "safe boot" option that should work similarly.
- If that fails, just boot from a Linux Live CD and mount your root partition from there, then modify it. Don't forget to unmount your root partition before you reboot!

Comment: what should I edit in the kernel command line to make it single user mode?

Comment: @Manoj Yes. You should append an `1` to the list of options.

Answer (score 1):

`chmod -x script` will remove its executable bit. It will not be run. Ever.

Comment: but I am not able to type any command as the output of the script keeps coming once I boot.

Comment: @Manoj Use a Live CD. Boot from it, mount your root partition, and do it from there.

Comment: Actually I am running Linux on an embedded system and So that option is not possible. Is there no way we can stop a running shell script ? :(